# Html2canvas do not render textbox fields

Tags: html, canvas, textbox, render, html2canvas

My screen captured canvas do not show any texts on my textboxes and do not show the selected field in my dropdown.
This is the Screenshot
[image: Screen capture here]

This is the script I am using

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

It should have datas that i Inserted in the textboxes. as seen on the graph below.
This is the code for my html2canvas

```
function screenshot() {
        html2canvas(document.body, {
            scrollY: -window.scrollY,
            crossOrigin: 'Anonymous',
            allowTaint: true,
            foreignObjectRendering: true,
        })
            .then(canvas => {
                imageData = canvas.toDataURL();
                console.log('Result from imageData', imageData)
                submissionData = prepData(imageData);
                JFCustomWidget.sendData(submissionData);
            })
            .catch(er => console.error(er));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the same issue in a Vue project with Vuetify. Turns out that the issue has to do with `foreignObjectRendering: true`.
Set it to `foreignObjectRendering: false` and the text will appear. At least that's my solution.

**Downside**: the quality of the image decreases, depending of the elements you render. E. g. shadows look pretty awful.

Comment: man you are a life saver. by setting it to false all the texts render.